# In draw.io is there a way to manually enter the width of a shape

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Afternoon. Is there a way in draw.io to enter the numeric dimensions of a shape? Currently I am fighting dragging the edges trying to make two shapes the same width.﻿

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the shape, go to Format->Edit Geometry... That will bring up the (x,y) of the top left corner of the shape, as well as the width and height. You can enter any new values and apply them.

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks so much for adding this feature.