# How do I change the dimensions of a draw.io shape?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have been trying to change the dimensions of a draw.io shape. There was a question about this previously ([In draw.io is there a way to manually enter the width of a shape](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57227/in-draw-io-is-there-a-way-to-manually-enter-the-width-of-a-shape)) which said that you should go to the Edit Geometry option in the format menu

However I can't see that anywhere - has it moved or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Format menu]

Answer (score 1):

Edit Geometry is under `arrange` in the menus. You can also just get one of the blue handles that appears on selection and move it.

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way to do it directly:

1. First, open Extras / Edit diagram
   [image]
2. Second edit dimensions manually as you wish

[image]

3. Result allied immediately:
   [image]